# Errors on graph for matplot correlation

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I am unable to get the correlation matrix to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

info = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tofighi/MachineLearning/master/datasets/heart.csv');

#Percentage of 0 and 1 
percentage = info['chd'].value_counts(normalize=True)
print(info['chd'].value_counts())
print(percentage)

#Missing values
print('\nNumber of missing values:')
print(info.isnull().sum())

#Categorical Variables
print('\n')
print(info.info())

#Maximum Correlation
f = plt.figure(figsize=(19, 15))
plt.matshow(info.corr(), fignum=f.number)
plt.xticks(range(info.shape[1]), info.columns, fontsize=14, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(range(info.shape[1]), info.columns, fontsize=14)
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
plt.title('Correlation Matrix', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Error

```
KeyError: (0.0, 0.0, 'row.names', 'black', 'center_baseline', 'right', 4543961435493219500, None, None, 72.0, <weakref at 0x7f25554ca548; dead>, 1.2)
```

Comment: The code is working fine in my system

Comment: @bigbounty I am using google colab

Answer (score 0):

I had to reconnect to hosted runtime and that seemed to fix the problem. There is a drop down menu besides the ram/disk where you can click to connect to hosted runtime.